# How to use ADB command in Flutter

Tags: flutter, adb

I'm writing a test application in Flutter to get data from available function/command in Android: in details I would like to access to Audio Codec device in order to read and write configuration register (like using i2cset and i2cget).

I read something about JNI but seems (correct me if I'm wrong) that in the latest versions of Flutter it has been removed.

Basically I would like to add a button in the UI like READ and send a command similar to

ADB i2cget -f -y 3 0x30 0x30

and return the data.

Thanks for your great help

Comment: If I understand correctly ADB interacts with the emulator (or the connected device). So whether you open the emulator running a flutter app or java app, ADB will still interact with emulator the same way.

Comment: It should be, I can easily connect in desktop app (like C# made) because the commands sent in terinal and by app are the same. In this case, being the app in user space, I need an example code to do this. Thanks for your reply

Comment: One step more: looking on the web seems that manage a process can help in what I need. In the example found (for Android environment) is to:

Create a process
Process p = null;
Get the runtime in root mode
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Create an output stream
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
loop along the command list I want into the DataOutputStream
...
os.writeBytes(tmpCmd.get(i)+"\n");
...
flush
os.flush();
This implementation seems working well for my target, now the point is "how to translate" in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run terminal commands using Dart [Process.run()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Process/run.html), but I don't think it's able to run an adb executable.